# I need help creating this IEEE reference list

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, ieee-style

I have found so many sites giving different codes on creating a IEEE reference list. And none of them helped me create my reference list. I just need to cite two references and I have been trying to figure out how to make this list for almost 2 hours now. One is from an E-book and the other is from a youtube video. The reference list has to look like this:

E-book

[#] Author's First Name Initial/s. Last Name, Book title: Subtitle. xth ed., vol. #, City of Publisher, Country: Publisher, year of publication, pp. #-# (if needed). [Online]. Available: URL, Accessed on: date.

Example: [17] H. Iqbal, Electric and Hybrid Vehicles: Design Fundamentals, 2th ed., Boca Raton, FL, USA: Taylor & Francis, 2010. [Online]. Available: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780444535658, Accessed on: Oct 03, 2017.

Video

[#] First Name Initial (s). Surname, Role in production, "Title of the work," Website name, year. [Format]. Available: URL, Accessed: Date.

Example: [5] Chalmers Library, Producent, "Welcome to Chalmers Library," Youtube, 2010. [Video]. Tillgänglig: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhj1hPrr4Ko, accessed on: 2017-10-02.

Answer (score 2):

> I just need to cite two references

If you have only two entries in the bibliography, it's not too burdensome to create the bibliography by hand, along the following lines.

In the preamble: load the `xurl` and `hyperref` packages.

In the main document, insert the following material:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{iqbal} H. Iqbal, Electric and Hybrid Vehicles: Design Fundamentals, 2th ed., 
Boca Raton, FL, USA: Taylor \& Francis, 2010. [Online]. Available: 
\url{http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9780444535658}, 
Accessed on: Oct 03, 2017.

\bibitem{chalmers} Chalmers Library, Producent, ``Welcome to Chalmers Library,'' 
Youtube, 2010. [Video]. Tillgänglig: 
\url{http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhj1hPrr4Ko}, 
Accessed on: 2017-10-02.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: You have no idea how much I appreciate what you just comment. THANK YOU SIR!

Comment: One thing, why does it not appear in my tableofcontents?

Comment: @Muhashka - The bibliography is, technically speaking, an unnumbered section-level item, and unnumbered sectioning headers are *not* included in the table of contents by default. There are various remedies. The easiest may be to insert `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` in the preamble and to recompile the document twice.

Comment: That worked, thanks again!

Comment: @Muhashka - You're welcome. Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer. ;-)

Comment: Ofcourse! I have many more websites now in my new rapport and I was wondering if there is an automatic way and not manually way to list my references with the same reference system as above in my examples.

Comment: @Muhashka - I think you would do well to teach yourself the basics of BibTeX.